# Installation of redis-3.0.7 on windows 10

Tags: windows, redis

How to install redis-3.0.7 on windows 10 ?. I have downloaded the package and followed the installation procedure on http://redis.io/download.

```
C:\Downloads\redis-3.0.7>make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick way is to use chocolatey as there is an approved redis-64 package available (redis-3.0.5 which is up to date).

see: https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64/

```
> choco install redis-64
```

Comment: it works very very fine!! thanks you solved my day!  :-D

Comment: as of 2018, it might much easyer to use WSL and compile latest versions.

Comment: sure @jgran I suppose is the correct way.. currently it is running thanks to chocolate but maybe I should be change the approach.

Comment: This is so easy

Comment: Thanks jgran. To add to it, I first installed choclatey on cmd.exe --> Run as administrator -->
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

Comment: Link is -->  https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation

Answer (score 4):

Redis doesn't support windows officially but there is unofficial port for redis on windows [github repo](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis), installation instructions are available on there